# Seal under a bronze vase

Tags: character-identification, seal

Can someone help me to read this seal found under an old looking bronze vase.
Can this seal allow to identify the manufacture of this vase and the period ?[image]

Comment: What I can tell is, only the center part is a character. Other strokes are just decorations.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that only the center part is a character. I guess it is combined with 禾+素